# Regex for amounts in text

Tags: php, regex

I'm able to match the prices that start with $ or EUR signs with code:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/(?:EUR|[$])\s*\d+(?:\.\d{2})?/",
    $textContent,
    $matches
);
var_dump($matches);
```

When input was:

[image: $ sign at start]

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "$15"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "$15"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "$15"
  }
}
```

When input was:
[image]

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "$

    300"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "$

    08"
        [2]=>
        string(6) "$

    300"
        [3]=>
        string(5) "$

    08"
  }
}
```

How to handle the prices where signs are after numerical value like 300.00 $ with optional space as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the second form as an alternate to your regex:

```
/(?:EUR|[$])\s*\d+(?:\.\d{2})?|\d+(?:\.\d{2})?\s*(?:EUR|[$])/
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/T9ZlW)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, maybe you might want to design an expression, similar to:

```
$re = '/^(?:EUR|[$€])?\s*\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*(?:EUR|[$€])?$/m';
$str = '$ 15
300$
$15
300  $
300 EUR
500 €
EUR 100.0
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/C2Iysc/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/C2Iysc/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.